# Suggestions to run a python script on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I currently have a python project which basically reads data from an excel file, transforms and formats it, performs intensive calculations on the formatted data, and generates an output. This output is written back on the same excel file.

The script is run using a Pyinstaller EXE which basically is packing all the required libraries and the code itself, so every user is not required to prep the environment to run the script.

Both, the script EXE and the Excel file, sit on the user's machine.

I need some suggestion on how this entire workflow could be achieved using AWS. Like what AWS services would be required etc.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: How would you envision the complete workflow? Would you want them to access a website in their browser, upload the file and then download the resulting file? If so, how would you want to manage security around it (eg who can access the website)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Hoping to keep the existing workflow. Users use an excel file, make changes in the input data, run the script, analyse output, make adjustments to input data, run the script again. This goes on until they are satisfied with the output.
Having a website would remove the simplicity - triggering the script from excel file itself vs upload and download to and from website. The users do not want to adapt to something which is new (and which requires them to perform additional tasks)

Comment: Ah! You say "triggering the script from excel file itself". Does that mean users don't run the script on the Excel file, but rather Excel "calls out" to somewhere to do processing? Is that how it happens today, with the Excel file calling out to your code on the same computer?

Answer (score 1):

One option would include using S3 to store the input and output files.  You could create a lambda function (or functions) that does the computing work and that writes the update back to S3.

You would need to include the Python dependencies in your deployment zip that you push to AWS Lambda or create a Lambda layer that has the dependencies.

You could build triggers to run on things like S3 events (a file being added to S3 triggers the Lambda), on a schedule (EventBridge rule invokes the Lambda according to a specific schedule), or on demand using an API (such as an API Gateway that users can invoke via a web browser or HTTP request).  It just depends on your need.